# How do I pass undefined vars to functions without E_NOTICE errors?

Tags: php

Pretty simple question really, how do I pass undefined vars to functions without E_NOTICE errors?

When passing undefined variables to functions such as isset(), no error is raised, but send the same to your own function and you'll get a Notice: Undefined offset: etc.

I have thought of a few reasons to want this today, but my current function is almost a clone of isset except it will check if *any* of the args are set, rather than all like isset(a,b,c) does.

```
function anyset()
{
    $argc = func_num_args();
    $argv = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $argc; $i++) 
        if (isset($argv[$i])) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Now, I have for example a giant 2d array of [x][y], into which values will be placed at random. I need to check the randomized co-ords contains anything "next" to it (x-1,y-1 to x+1,y+1) etc.

I do not want to do a loop of 20,000,000 and initialise each variable. I just want to send 9 vars and check if any are already set.

```
while (anyset($items[$x-1][$y-1],$items[$x][$y-1],$items[$x+1][$y-1],
              $items[$x-1][$y],$items[$x][$y],$items[$x+1][$y],
              $items[$x-1][$y+1],$items[$x][$y+1],$items[$x+1][$y+1]));
```

Like so.

I could just do isset(x) || isset(x) || isset(x) but that doesn't look very nice.

**Is there a way to allow undefined variables to pass to my function without raising errors?**

Not interested in taking the easy option ;)

Thanks for reading!

\o

**Update:** 12 April 2012, 21:03
Looks like there is no special feature allowing this to happen. So either pass like anyset(@$array[0], @$array[1]) etc, or just wrap everything in a thousand issets like so:

```
while (isset($items[$x-1][$y-1]) || isset($items[$x][$y-1]) || isset($items[$x+1][$y-1]) || 
       isset($items[$x-1][$y])   || isset($items[$x][$y])   || isset($items[$x+1][$y]) || 
       isset($items[$x-1][$y+1]) || isset($items[$x][$y+1]) || isset($items[$x+1][$y+1]));
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: Simple thought, just add the error-neutralizer @ just before the error-raising function ? `$result = @youFunction()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have three options:

- Use isset to handle the logic properly (isset($x) || isset($y) || isset($z))
- Wrap everything in isset() and then have your function check if any of the arguements are true (kind of bleh)
- Use @ to suppress errors (also bleh)

An example of @ would be:

```
function a($a) { } a(@$x);
```

You should remember though that notices exist for a reason.  I avoid error suppressing.  It seems hacky to me.  I would just properly wrap everything in isset().  It's a lot more verbose, but also, in my opinion anyway, more correct.

Comment: I see, I thought of that but I also thought it was a bit hacky. Thought there might be some magical way of allowing undefined variables to pass through as null/unset. No problem, I guess I'll use 9 issets! Thanks.

Comment: @AdamKDean Well, there's always the option to adjust the error reporting level.  I would have mentioned that as an option, except for it's not specific to this section of code.  It would be specific to the entire run of code.  For example error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); would ignore notices.  The problem would be though, it would ignore *all* notices, not just using an undefined variable.  You could wrap just the function call in error_reporting() and then revert the error reporting to normal, but that seems even hackier to me.

Comment: @AdamKDean another option would be to prefix the entire function with @.  I thought that you had to prefix each variable individually, but just tested Claaker's suggestion in the comments, and apparently you can prefix the entire function to suppress the notices.  This might had some errors you don't mean to though.

Comment: I agree, ideally there would be a way of sending through null variables, maybe something like function anyset($argc, nullable params $argv), though that is just starting to look like C#.

Comment: Eh, I like the behaviour.  In fact, I would probably have made it an error, not a notice if I had made the decision.  I can see where it can be annoying though in situations like this where you're forced to do a lot of verbose isset() calling.

Comment: Indeed, the behaviour works how it should, but it would be nice to override it with function for things like this.

Answer (score 10):

Pass by reference will work for defined arguments.

```
function my_isset(&$k) { ... }

$bool = my_isset($_POST['hi']);
```

Comment: That will still throw a notice if the 'hi' key of $_POST does not exist.

Comment: If passed by reference (&), it will not throw a notice. This will not work with func_get_args. You could try to use debug_backtrace, but a notice will still be triggered

Comment: I think this is the correct answer - passing by reference will stop the warning from being generated.

Comment: On php 7.3 passing by reference stopped the warning messages. Therefore, this seems to be the correct answer (+1).

Answer (score 5):

`isset` is a bit special as it is actually a PHP language construct rather than a function [[1]](http://php.net/isset#refsect1-function.isset-notes).

If a variable is undefined, you can't really pass it because it isn't defined (hence the warning).

As stated in comments, you can suppress the warnings by prepending an `@` to the variable which will prevent a warning from being emitted if it is not set.  Then within the function you can check to see if the value is null or try using `isset` to see if it is registered.

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware of that, although I did consider that it could be a special built in feature. Buggger. Thanks anyway, guess issets will have to be the way to go!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this will work for you? It's a little bit hackish, but I think what you want is not quite possible without lazy evaluation of function arguments.

```
if (atLeastOneIsSet($myArray, 1, 3, 4, 6)) doSomething();

function atLeastOneIsSet(array $arr) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 1; $i < func_num_args(); ++$i)
        if (isset($arr[$args[$i]])) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Edit: oops, logic issues.

Comment: Setting this up to work with a 2d array would make it worse than just using issets. Can you imagine atLeastOneIsSet($array, array(0,0), array(1,0), array(1,1)) etc? Thanks though, interesting concept!

Comment: @AdamKDean Oops, I think I was in too much of a hurry to post. These darn PHP questions always make me feel so rushed!