# Pass undefined index into PHP function

Tags: php, parameter-passing, argument-passing, optional-parameters

I have a function that looks somewhat like this:

```
function name( param1 = default, param2 = default, param3 = default) {...}
```

I'm calling the function by passing elements of an array as the parameters like this:

```
name( $param['foo'], $param['bar'], $param['hello'] );
```

My question is -- if one (or more) of the elements passed in the function call is undefined, how is it handled within the function itself? I ask because I am trying to call the function but I have no way of knowing if any of the elements are defined.

Inside of the function, I tried debugging a parameter passed through using `isset()`, `is_null()`, and `empty()` and I got false, true, and true respectively. This leads me to believe that since something is actually being passed in, the default value is not set. If anyone could explain how something like this is handled I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hm, if you pass array values, why just not pass the array itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass undefined vars to functions without E\_NOTICE errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130715/how-do-i-pass-undefined-vars-to-functions-without-e-notice-errors)

Comment: @bksi It's totally possible but I was thinking if I knew exactly which array elements I would need, I might as well just pass those.

Comment: You can check them after passing in the method you pass them.

Comment: The default value is only used if no argument was passed. If you pass an argument, it will be used, even if it's undefined.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I figured was happening but I didn't see anything in the documentation so I couldn't be quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function generally has no clue, and generally doesn't care, WHERE an argument came from. e.g.

```
$x = 2;
foo($x);
foo(2);
```

As far as `foo()` is concerned, it'll just see `2` come in, and nothing will tell it "this 2 was hardcoded" or "this 2 was passed in via a variable".

If you pass in an undefined variable, then the function itself will see a `null` value arrive, and PHP will spit out a warning about using the undefined variable, BEFORE the function code ever has a chance to start executing.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it is passing, NULL which is a constant value designated to represent a null or uninitialized value.

Answer (score 0):

---

Calling an undefined index in an array results in a warning.

Two rules for you:

- Pass/use only defined things
- Never disable warnings/errors

Example:

```
$params = ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => null, 'nextKey' => null];
```

A common approach is to pass the (sub)array:

```
myMethod($params);
```

Your method takes the elements it need.